Query performance degrade after upgrade from MySQLv5.6 to v5.7
I upgraded the MySQL Server from v5.6 to v5.7 and since then I see query performance degrade. For example, I have the following select query that selects some columns and has a single column in the WHERE clause and that column is a part of the Primary Key along with other columns.
Query:
SELECT
StatsID,
AdTypeID,
StatsActionTypeID AS ActionTypeID,
ActionKey,
SubActionKey,
StatsFeatureID1 AS featureId1,
SegmentID1 AS segmentId1,
StatsFeatureValue1 AS valueId1,
StatsFeatureID2 AS featureId2,
SegmentID2 AS segmentId2,
StatsFeatureValue2 AS valueId2,
Coef
FROM Stats
WHERE
StatsID IN (........);
The table has the following columns in PK :
PRIMARY KEY (StatsID,AdTypeID,StatsActionTypeID,ActionKey,SubActionKey,StatsFeatureID1,SegmentID1,StatsFeatureValue1,StatsFeatureID2,SegmentID2,StatsFeatureValue2).
Explain plan in v5.6 :

Explain plan in v5.7 :

I tried creating a secondary index on StatsID column:
ALTER TABLE Stats ADD INDEX idx_statsid (StatsID); and checked the performance but that didn't helped much.
I compared the following variables : optimizer_switch values on both v5.6 and v5.7.
v5.6:
index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,favor_range_scan=off
v5.7:
index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on,prefer_ordering_index=on,favor_range_scan=off
I did the following changes with the following values:
SET GLOBAL optimizer_switch='duplicateweedout=off';
SET GLOBAL optimizer_switch='condition_fanout_filter=off';
SET GLOBAL optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';
SET GLOBAL optimizer_switch='prefer_ordering_index=off';
and checked again but that didn't made any difference. Can anyone suggest anything here to improve the query's performance because this query is a simple select query?

According to execution plans 5.7 version reads more than twice rows then 5.6 version. It is supposed to be slower.
How many rows is there in the table? Maybe full scan will be more efficient?
How many values are in IN clause?

@MarcinBadtke : The total rows in the table are ~6.65M, select select query's output returns ~1.70M. There are 1500 values in the IN clause. I don't understand why v5.7 is reading more than twice rows than v5.6. I had changed the optimizer parameter as per v5.6 in v5.7.

looks like there are more rows now in 5.7 version then was in 5.6 version. Maybe in IN clause some values are doubled? Anyways 1.7M of 6.65M is ca 25%. Full scan should be more efficient. Try SET @@explain_format=TREE; and then explain . Or explain analyze 

@MarcinBadtke : explain_format=TREE is not supported in v5.7, I am getting : Error Code: 1791. Unknown EXPLAIN format name: 'TREE'.

@jeremycole : Can you recommend something here ?
